# How to load local gltf files in Android studio using google's scene viewer? (Android 13)

Tags: android, permissions, 3d, arcore, gltf

Im building an app on android studio where I use https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/scene-viewer to display gltf models.

I've tried giving the absolute path of my phone's gltf file  ("/storage/emulated/0.../scene.gltf") in below code's file parameter but whenever I start the app, it crashes displaying a message "Couldn't load object" "Looks that there's something wrong with this object". Does that mean that the google's scene viewer can't display local gltf files?

```
Intent sceneViewerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri intentUri =
Uri.parse("https://arvr.google.com/scene-viewer/1.0").buildUpon()
     .appendQueryParameter("file", "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/master/2.0/Avocado/glTF/Avocado.gltf")
     .appendQueryParameter("mode", "ar_only")
     .build();
sceneViewerIntent.setData(intentUri);
sceneViewerIntent.setPackage("com.google.ar.core");
startActivity(sceneViewerIntent);
```